# C++ How to use a class with template argument list when the template argument type(s) is still unknown?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a method definition taking a template argument list. In that method i need to use another generic class passing in the template argument type as the template argument type of the method. How to achieve this?

```
template <typename T>
void MyQueue<T>::push(T* object)
{
    Wrapper<T>* wr = new Wrapper(object); //error here
    if (*tail)
    {
        tail->next = wr;
    }
    else
    {
        head = wr;
    }
    tail = wr;
    wr->next = nullptr;
}
```

error:

```
error C2955: 'Wrapper': use of class template requires template argument list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Wrapper` is a class template, so you cannot say `new Wrapper(args)` in this context. You simply need to add the template parameter in the right place:

```
Wrapper<T>* wr = new Wrapper<T>(object);
                            ^^^
```

The hint is in the type of the pointer on the LHS.